# jQuery datepicker inline-format outputs long date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

**html**

```
<div id="expire"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="expire">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#expire").datepicker({
        altFormat: "YY-MM-DD",
        dateFormat: "YY-MM-DD",
        onSelect: function(){
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('input[name=expire]').val(dateObject); 
        }
    });
```

When using the above my datepicker is inline and when I click a date the value of the hidden field ends up like

> Sat Feb 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Is there a way to change this so its like such

> 2013-02-16

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer is**

```
$("#expire").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var dateObject = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
            $('input[name=expire]').val(dateObject); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d  = new Date(dateObject);

var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var fulldate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year
 $('input[name=expire]').val(fulldate);
```

Comment: That's not `YY-MM-DD`, it's `D-M-YY`